# Cannot implicitly convert type 'UltimateSurvival.ItemProperty.Value' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject'

Tags: unity, c#

As the title states, I am getting this error and I cannot figure out why. I have tried Google and I couldn't find a precise answer as to how to fix it.

Error:

> Assets\Ultimate Survival\Scripts\By Namespace\UltimateSurvival\Inventory\InventoryController.cs(189,32): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UltimateSurvival.ItemProperty.Value' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject'

Code:

```
public bool Try_DropItem(SavableItem item, Slot parentSlot = null)
{
    if(item && item.ItemData.WorldObject)
    {
        var cameraTransform = GameController.WorldCamera.transform;

        GameObject w_Object = item.ItemData.WorldObject;

        if (item.ItemData.IsBuildable)
        {
            w_Object = item.GetPropertyValue("Bag");
        }

        GameObject droppedItem = Instantiate(w_Object, cameraTransform.position + cameraTransform.TransformVector(m_DropOffset), Random.rotation) as GameObject;

        var rigidbody = droppedItem.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        if(rigidbody)
        {
            rigidbody.angularVelocity = Random.rotation.eulerAngles * m_DropAngularFactor;
            rigidbody.AddForce(cameraTransform.forward * m_DropSpeed, ForceMode.VelocityChange);

            Physics.IgnoreCollision(m_Player.GetComponent<Collider>(), droppedItem.GetComponent<Collider>());
        }

        var pickup = droppedItem.GetComponent<ItemPickup>();
        if(pickup)
            pickup.ItemToAdd = item;

        if(parentSlot)
            parentSlot.ItemHolder.SetItem(null);

        return true;

    }

    return false;
}
```

ItemProperty:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace UltimateSurvival
{
[Serializable]
public class ItemCategory
{
    public string Name { get { return m_Name; } }

    public ItemData[] Items { get { return m_Items; } }

    [SerializeField]
    private string m_Name;

    [SerializeField]
    private ItemData[] m_Items;
}

/// <summary>
/// The data / definition for an item.
/// </summary>
[Serializable]
public class ItemData
{
    public string Name { get { return m_Name; } }

    public string DisplayName { get { return m_DisplayName; } }

    public int Id { get { return m_Id; } set { m_Id = value; } }

    public string Category { get { return m_Category; } set { m_Category = value; } }

    public Sprite Icon { get { return m_Icon; } }

    public GameObject WorldObject { get { return m_WorldObject; } }

    public string[] Descriptions { get { return m_Descriptions; } }

    public int StackSize { get { return m_StackSize; } }

    public List<ItemProperty.Value> PropertyValues { get { return m_PropertyValues; } }

    public bool IsBuildable { get { return m_IsBuildable; } }

    public bool IsCraftable { get { return m_IsCraftable; } }

    public Recipe Recipe { get { return m_Recipe; } }

    [SerializeField]
    private string m_Name;

    [SerializeField]
    private string m_DisplayName;

    [SerializeField]
    private int m_Id;

    [SerializeField]
    private string m_Category;

    [SerializeField]
    private Sprite m_Icon;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject m_WorldObject;

    [SerializeField]
    [Multiline]
    private string[] m_Descriptions;

    [SerializeField]
    private int m_StackSize = 1;

    [SerializeField]
    private List<ItemProperty.Value> m_PropertyValues;

    [SerializeField]
    private bool m_IsBuildable;

    [SerializeField]
    private bool m_IsCraftable;

    [SerializeField]
    private Recipe m_Recipe;
}

/// <summary>
/// A SavableItem is an instance of an item, which can have it's own properties, vs ItemData which is just the data for an item, just the definition.
/// </summary>
[Serializable]
public class SavableItem
{
    public Message<ItemProperty.Value> PropertyChanged = new Message<ItemProperty.Value>();

    public Message StackChanged = new Message();

    public bool Initialized { get; private set; }

    public ItemData ItemData { get; private set; }

    public int Id { get { return ItemData.Id; } }

    public string Name { get { return ItemData.Name; } }

    public int CurrentInStack { get { return m_CurrentInStack; } set { m_CurrentInStack = value; StackChanged.Send(); } }

    public List<ItemProperty.Value> CurrentPropertyValues { get { return m_CurrentPropertyValues; } }

    [SerializeField]
    private int m_CurrentInStack;

    [SerializeField]
    private List<ItemProperty.Value> m_CurrentPropertyValues;


    public static implicit operator bool(SavableItem item) { return item != null; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public SavableItem(ItemData data, int currentInStack = 1, List<ItemProperty.Value> customPropertyValues = null)
    {
        CurrentInStack = Mathf.Clamp(currentInStack, 1, data.StackSize);

        if(customPropertyValues != null)
            m_CurrentPropertyValues = CloneProperties(customPropertyValues);
        else
            m_CurrentPropertyValues = CloneProperties(data.PropertyValues);

        ItemData = data;
        Initialized = true;

        for(int i = 0;i < m_CurrentPropertyValues.Count;i ++)
            m_CurrentPropertyValues[i].Changed.AddListener(On_PropertyChanged);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Must be called after the item was loaded / deserialized, (not required when the item is created at runtime, through the constructor).
    /// </summary>
    public void OnLoad(ItemDatabase itemDatabase)
    {
        if(itemDatabase)
        {
            ItemData data;
            if(itemDatabase.FindItemById(Id, out data))
            {
                ItemData = data;
                Initialized = true;

                for(int i = 0;i < m_CurrentPropertyValues.Count;i ++)
                    m_CurrentPropertyValues[i].Changed.AddListener(On_PropertyChanged);
            }
            else
                Debug.LogErrorFormat("[SavableItem] - This item couldn't be initialized and will not function properly. No item with the name {0} was found in the database!", Name);
        }
        else
            Debug.LogError("[SavableItem] - This item couldn't be initialized and will not function properly. The item database provided is null!");
    }

    public string GetDescription(int index)
    {
        string description = string.Empty;
        if(index > -1 && ItemData.Descriptions.Length > index)
        {
            try
            {
                description = string.Format(ItemData.Descriptions[index], m_CurrentPropertyValues.ToArray());
            }
            catch
            {
                Debug.LogError("[SavableItem] - You tried to access a property through the item description, but the property doesn't exist. The item name is: " + Name);
            }
        }

        return description;
    }

    public bool HasProperty(string name)
    {
        if(!Initialized)
        {
            Debug.LogError("[SavableItem] - This SavableItem is not initialized, probably it was loaded and not initialized! (call OnLoad() after loading / deserializing).");
            return false;
        }

        for(int i = 0;i < m_CurrentPropertyValues.Count;i ++)
            if(m_CurrentPropertyValues[i].Name == name)
                return true;

        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use this if you are sure the item has this property.
    /// </summary>
    public ItemProperty.Value GetPropertyValue(string name)
    {
        ItemProperty.Value propertyValue = null;

        if(!Initialized)
        {
            Debug.LogError("[SavableItem] - This SavableItem is not initialized, probably it was loaded and not initialized! (call OnLoad() after loading / deserializing).");
            return null;
        }

        for(int i = 0;i < m_CurrentPropertyValues.Count;i ++)
            if(m_CurrentPropertyValues[i].Name == name)
            {
                propertyValue = m_CurrentPropertyValues[i];
                break;
            }

        return propertyValue;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use this if you are NOT sure the item has this property.
    /// </summary>
    public bool FindPropertyValue(string name, out ItemProperty.Value propertyValue)
    {
        propertyValue = null;

        if(!Initialized)
        {
            Debug.LogError("[SavableItem] - This SavableItem is not initialized, probably it was loaded and not initialized! (call OnLoad() after loading / deserializing).");
            return false;
        }

        for(int i = 0;i < m_CurrentPropertyValues.Count;i ++)
            if(m_CurrentPropertyValues[i].Name == name)
            {
                propertyValue = m_CurrentPropertyValues[i];
                return true;
            }

        return false;
    }

    private List<ItemProperty.Value> CloneProperties(List<ItemProperty.Value> properties)
    {
        List<ItemProperty.Value> list = new List<ItemProperty.Value>();
        for(int i = 0;i < properties.Count;i ++)
            list.Add(properties[i].GetClone());

        return list;
    }

    private void On_PropertyChanged(ItemProperty.Value propertyValue)
    {
        PropertyChanged.Send(propertyValue);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Looks like the problem is this line `w_Object = item.GetPropertyValue("Bag");`. `w_Object` wants a `UnityEngine.GameObject`, but `GetPropertyValue` is returning an `UltimateSurvival.ItemProperty.Value` instead. Can you show us what that type looks like, so we can recommend ways to fix this?

Comment: the type `UltimateSurvival.ItemProperty.Value` is returning a string

Comment: Okay, and what's your plan for using that string information to select/produce a `GameObject`? It's a bit tough to know whether we should look it up in a map, or use Find to look for a scene object with that name, or construct a new `GameObject` using that string, etc. without understanding your application context.

Comment: i want to produce a gameobject and the title of the prefab is stored in that `UltimateSurvival.ItemProperty.Value`, or instead of having it setup like that can i just reference a prefab in `GameObject droppedItem = Instantiate(w_Object, cameraTransform.position + cameraTransform.TransformVector(m_DropOffset), Random.rotation) as GameObject;` where instead of w_Object can i just reference a prefab name there?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
w_Object = item.GetPropertyValue("Bag");
```

You've declared `w_Object` is a `GameObject`, but this function is returning an `UltimateSurvival.ItemProperty.Value` (which you say is effectively a string? We can't see that part in your question...)

Unity doesn't know how to convert that value into the `GameObject` you want to reference, so we have to tell it what we want it to do.

> I want to produce a gameobject and the title of the prefab is stored in that UltimateSurvival.ItemProperty.Value

Here's one simple way to do it, where you populate a shortlist of prefabs in the Unity Inspector.

```
public List<GameObject> prefabs;

GameObject InstantiatePrefabByName(string name) {
    // Find a prefab in our list that has a name matching this string.
    var source = prefabs.Find(prefab => prefab.name == name);

    // If we didn't find a hit, throw an error that helps us diagnose the issue.
    if(source == null) {
        Debug.LogErrorFormat(
            "Tried to instantiate unknown prefab name, \"{0}\"", 
            name
        );
        // Return a dummy game object as the best we can do.
        return new GameObject(name + " (Missing)");
    }

    // Instantiate our prefab and return the instance.
    return Instantiate(source);
}
```

Then you can call this with something like...

```
// I assume you get your string value with ToString() - if not, swap this part.
string prefabName = item.GetPropertyValue("Bag").ToString();

// Now we call our prefab-finding-and-spawning function with this string.
w_Object = InstantiatePrefabByName(prefabName);
```